# Synchronizing Local Accounts to Domain Accounts

Tags: windows-xp, active-directory

I'm wondering if there is a way to simply my process(es).

Currently I have Windows XP workstations, Windows Server 2008 R2, Active Directory and Domain Services, Folder Redirection.

When a user currently logs in to a workstation, their documents, etc. are synched to the workstation and the user can begin working.  However, there are a multitude of programs that we use in our environment that require higher than Power User privileges on the workstation.  So in order for some users to function, we have to add the user to the Local User Accounts, and set them as an Administrator.

Is there a way for me to eliminate this?  Is there a way for me to maintain my current setup yet not have to visit each station and set up users as Administrators for some of their software to properly function?

Comment: You can add the domain user to the local groups, I'm looking for a more automated way to do this without having to physically go to the workstation and add the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add domain users to local groups. Domain-wide, this can be done using [Restricted Groups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785631.aspx).

Comment: This may have answered my question, I will test this out and verify.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm marking this as answered unless proven otherwise!  Thanks for the help Grawity!

Comment: This is correct, but there are two ways to do it. One way will wipe your local admins group with everyone *except* the user you specify. The other way will add your user to the local admins group. Be sure you test and know the difference before you put it into prod. I did this once the wrong way by accident :)

Comment: @BoxerBucks: Care to explain which way is the Right One? (Feel free to edit the post.)

Comment: The "right one" to me is the one that adds your account to the local admins group. In the security setting make sure you specify your account as the account to act on and that you specify it as a member of local admins. It's easy to think to put Local Admins as the group to act on and to add your account to it. That is called "rip and replace" and it will replace local admins with just your account or group as opposed to adding it as another member.

Answer (score 0):

Create a group in AD (lets call it localadmins).  In group policy set the [restrictive group](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785631%28WS.10%29.aspx) settings on administrators to add that group (localadmins) to administrator.  Add the users to that locadmins group as needed.